# Using Hubspot Jinja code. Need to align images at top of div tag

Tags: html, css

I am using Hubspot's platform to create an email template. Using the Jinja code, I have established three columns that will contain content. The first of these columns will have an image at the top . The problem is that I cannot get the image to align at the top of the  container. Instead, the image is displayed about 5-8px from the top of the  tag.

Here's how my code looks:

```
<div style="display:block;"><p>{% linked_image "Video Image" label="Video Image",   width="180", height="165" %}</p>

<p>{% rich_text "Video Description Header" label="Video Description Header" %}</p>
<p>{% rich_text "Video Description Text" label="Video Description Text" %}</p>
         </div>
```

Using the code above, the "Video Image" does not line up with the top of the  box. What should I do?

Thanks in advance,
OB

Comment: Have you reset margin and padding values?

Comment: No. But one doesn't need to. The Hubspot platform is not exactly rendering web pages. It's more about creating HTML for email. You can use style-ing but not style sheets.